# Python treeview, double click to copy file but change displayed filename according to matching ID in separate file

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

The script below makes a treeview of files in a folder and when I double click a file, it is copied to the clipboard which works perfectly for my use case.

[image]

The filenames (photos) in the folder are stored anonymously while I have a another txt file that contains the names to each ID:

[image]

How can I, in the treeview in the GUI, get it to display the names from the ID txt file instead of the filename but continue to copy the file when I double click it?

```
import os
import subprocess
import shutil
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, path):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, show='tree')
        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set, xscroll=xsb.set)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text=path, anchor='w')

        self.abspath = os.path.abspath(path)
        
        self.tree.bind("<Double-Button-1>",self.copy_to_clipboard)

        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0)
        ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.grid()

        self.store_path = []
        self.reload()

    def copy_to_clipboard(self,event,*args):
        item = self.tree.focus()
        self.store_path.append(self.tree.item(item,"text"))
        
        absolute_path = self.find_absolutePath(item)
        cmd = r"ls '{}' | Set-Clipboard".format(absolute_path) # if you only want the contents of folder to be copied

        subprocess.run(["powershell", "-command", cmd], shell=True)  # windows specific

        print("copied")

    def find_absolutePath(self, item):

        parent_id = self.tree.parent(item)
        if parent_id:
            parent = self.tree.item(parent_id, 'text')
            self.store_path.append(parent)
            return self.find_absolutePath(parent_id)

        else:
            absolute_path = os.path.join(*self.store_path[::-1])
            self.store_path = []
            return absolute_path

                        
    def reload(self):
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())
        root = self.tree.insert('', 'end', text=self.abspath, open=True)
        self.process_directory(root, self.abspath)
  
    
    def process_directory(self, parent, path):
        try:
            for p in os.listdir(path):
                abspath = os.path.join(path, p)
                isdir = os.path.isdir(abspath)
                oid = self.tree.insert(parent, 'end', text=p, open=False)
                if isdir:
                    self.process_directory(oid, abspath)
        except PermissionError:
            pass
    

root = tk.Tk()
path_to_my_project = r'Path\to\project '
app = App(root, path=path_to_my_project)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the ID text in the Treeview item's `text` attribute, and the filename as a column `value` , then just hide the additional column

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, show='tree', columns='hide_me')
self.tree.item(item, text=id_text, values=path_to_file)
self.tree.column(0, width=0, minwidth=0)
```

Then you can just query the `text` or `values` separately as needed